# How to add an extra variable to login and authenticate it?

Tags: customization, filters, login

I want to add an extra variable to my custom login and to authenticate it to then add it to an SQL database.

My custom login:

```
<?php
require('wp-load.php');
require('site_config.php');

function FilterMid() {
    $x = '
            <p class="login-extra">
                <label for="user_extra">Extra</label>
                <input type="text" class="text" id="user_extra" name="user_extra" />
            </p>';
    return $x;
}

function validate_login_extra() {
    $ex = $_POST["user_extra"];
    db_insert("butikk_sjekk", "butikk", "$store"); //custom mysqli function
}
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user','validate_login_extra',10,2);

if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // Display WordPress login form:
    add_filter( 'login_form_middle', 'FilterMid' );
    wp_login_form();
    exit;
}
```

The thing is. On my login form I can without problem see the extra field. But I cannot figure out how to capture the extra field, authenticate it, than store it. Tried searching the web, and reading the wordpress codex with no help.